# Please assist me to escalate this issue

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Please assist me to escalate this issue

Is the above sentence correct?

or

Should I use 'in' or 'on' or 'with' in place of 'to'?

Comment: "... assist me to ..." is not very idiomatic.

Comment: If I had to use *assist*, I’d probably say, “Please assist me in escalating this issue.”

Comment: Is the focus of the question on *assist* or on *escalate*? This use of the latter is a relatively new element of the bureaucratic jargon, which will make many people cringe (even, though it is not 'incorrect', within that jargon).

Answer (score 1):

“in escalating” is better.
Or: “help me escalate”.

Comment: Why? Please provide supporting evidence.